# How to set custom author format in BibTex

Tags: bibtex

I have the following citation:

```
@article{Sun_2013,
    Author = {Sun, Xiaochen and Vilar, Santiago and Tatonetti, Nicholas P.},
    Date-Added = {2016-06-02 14:05:28 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-06-02 14:05:28 +0000},
    Doi = {10.1126/scitranslmed.3006667},
    Eprint = {http://stm.sciencemag.org/content/5/205/205rv1.full.pdf},
    Issn = {1946-6234},
    Journal = {Science Translational Medicine},
    Number = {205},
    Pages = {205rv1--205rv1},
    Publisher = {American Association for the Advancement of Science},
    Title = {High-Throughput Methods for Combinatorial Drug Discovery},
    Volume = {5},
    Year = {2013},
}
```

That produces the below output in using `\bibliographystyle{plain}`

> Xiaochen Sun, Santiago Vilar, and Nicholas P. Tatonetti.
>   High-throughput methods for combinatorial drug discovery. Science
>   Translational Medicine, 5(205):205rv1–205rv1, 2013.

I want if i have more than two authors i can replace rest with et al. I have tried this bibtex scripts but i can not get rid of the `and` before et al.

```
@article{Sun_2013,
    Author = {Sun X and Vilar S and Tatonetti NP and et al.},
    Date-Added = {2016-06-02 14:05:28 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-06-02 14:05:28 +0000},
    Doi = {10.1126/scitranslmed.3006667},
    Eprint = {http://stm.sciencemag.org/content/5/205/205rv1.full.pdf},
    Issn = {1946-6234},
    Journal = {Science Translational Medicine},
    Number = {205},
    Pages = {205rv1--205rv1},
    Publisher = {American Association for the Advancement of Science},
    Title = {High-Throughput Methods for Combinatorial Drug Discovery},
    Volume = {5},
    Year = {2013},
}
```

I got this:

> Sun X, Vilar S, and et al. High-throughput methods for combinatorial drug
>   discovery. Science Translational Medicine, 5(205):205rv1–205rv1, 2013.

**Desired output:**

Please can anyone show me how i can set it in the following format:

> Sun X, Vilar S, et al. High-throughput methods for combinatorial drug
>   discovery. Science Translational Medicine, 5(205):205rv1–205rv1, 2013.

Comment: Can you consider doing it with `biblatex`?